# Setting log levels for all classes in log4j

Tags: log4j

Is there a way to set log levels for all classes in a package in log4j? I don't want to add a line for each class in my package in log4j.properties

So if I have a package such as : com.my.package and class1, class2, class3 in that package , is there a concise way to set

```
log4j.logger.com.my.package.class1=INFO
log4j.logger.com.my.package.class2=INFO
log4j.logger.com.my.package.class3=INFO
```

I tried:

```
log4j.logger.com.my.package.*=INFO but that does not seem to work.
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Try `log4j.logger.com.my.package=INFO`

Comment: That does not work either...forgot to mention that earlier. That seemed more logical as I don't have a logger named  log4j.logger.com.my.package=INFO

Comment: Of course you need to replace the `com.my.package` part with your own package name...